# DropDown do bootstrap não funciona

Tags: bootstrap, dropdown

Pesquisei sobre o assunto,encontrei alguns exemplos, porem o DropDown não funciona.
Alguem tem alguma idéia ?

Segue o código :

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>

    <script style="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script style="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <script style="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
      }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Está no final do código {<script style="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <script style="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>}

Comment: Funcionou Darlei. Era só isso mesmo, passei o JQuery pra cima e funcionou. 

Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Não estou achando o botão pra colocar como solucionado.